# C++ Building Winsparkle for VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, makefile, cmake, nmake

The documentation for winsparkle states that if we want to build it from source all we need to do is to run `WinSparkle-2012.sln` . Unfortunately I cannot build this project as I get these errors

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\any.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   2   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\appbase.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   3   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\checkboxcmn.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   4   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\arrstr.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   5   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\artprov.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   6   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\bmpbase.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   7   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\btncmn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   8   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\colourcmn.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   9   error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\cmdproc.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   10  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\cmdline.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   11  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\appcmn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   12  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\clntdata.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   13  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\config.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   14  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\containr.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   15  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\convauto.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   16  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\ctrlcmn.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   17  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dcbufcmn.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   18  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dcbase.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   19  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\ctrlsub.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   20  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dircmn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   21  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dlgcmn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   22  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dobjcmn.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   23  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dpycmn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   24  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dynarray.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   25  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\dynlib.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   26  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\encconv.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   27  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\filefn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   28  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\filename.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   29  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\file.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   30  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\evtloopcmn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   31  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\event.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   32  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\fontcmn.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   33  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\framecmn.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   34  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\gaugecmn.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   35  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\gbsizer.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   36  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\hash.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   37  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\hashmap.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   38  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\gdicmn.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   39  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\init.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   40  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\iconbndl.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   41  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\list.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   42  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\log.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   43  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\ipcbase.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   44  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\layout.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   45  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\menucmn.cpp': No such file or directory C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   46  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\longlong.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   47  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\matrix.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   48  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\module.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   49  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\modalhook.cpp': No such file or directory   C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   50  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\msgout.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   51  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\mousemanager.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   52  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\object.cpp': No such file or directory  C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
Error   53  error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'wxWidgets\src\common\panelcmn.cpp': No such file or directory    C:\winsparkle\3rdparty\c1xx
```

These files do not exist in the project. Is there anything that I need to do is to generate these files ??

Answer (score 1):

I believe you didn't init/update submodules, so you didn't get wxWidgets, they explain in their readme:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle.git
$ cd winsparkle
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Comment: This worked.  If you download the source zip directly from the web site, it doesn't include the wxWidgets and the project won't compile.